# HTTP POST using JSON in java to bitbucket server returns 400 as response code

Tags: java, json, post, bitbucket

I am trying to do a POST request for adding comment field to bitbucket server using Java. I am always getting Response code as 400.

```
String data=  "text=" + params;

String restUrl = m_ServerName + "/" + restUrl;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(restUrl);
post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + m_EncodedLogin);  
post.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, Consts.UTF_8));
CloseableHttpResponse response = m_HttpClient.execute(post);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Comment: Maybe your are not using the right authentication method.
Please refer to https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication

Comment: @TreantBG It works fine for HTTP GET request, so I think there is no issue with Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the issue is with the string data variable I was forming. Working code is as follows:-

```
String data=  "{\"text\"=" + \"params\" + "}";

String restUrl = m_ServerName + "/" + restUrl;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(restUrl);
post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + m_EncodedLogin);  
post.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, Consts.UTF_8));
CloseableHttpResponse response = m_HttpClient.execute(post);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())
```